# div#myID { } vs #myID div { } / Which CSS syntax is recommended?

Tags: html, css

Are those CSS selectors do the same or there are differences?

```
div#myID {  }  

#myID div {   }
```

If they are the same, which one is recommended?

Comment: Read here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, they both do something different, so there is nothing to recommend.

- `div#myID` selects a `div` with ID `myID`. This can be expressed shorter with just `#myID`.
- `#myID div` selects all `div`s that are descendants of the element with ID `myID`.

Comment: div#myID can only be safely shortened to #myID if the CSS is only used with a single HTML file. Otherwise, you might have, say, a p element with an id of "myID" in one file and a div with with a id of "myID" in a different file, and only want to apply the styling when the id="myID" element is a div. Probably not good practice to do such a thing, but definitely possible and valid.

Answer (score 4):

Your selectors are completely different.

The first one combines two different selectors to match every element which is both `div` and `#myID` — every `<div>` with ID `myID`.

The second one uses the descendant combinator to match all `div`s which are inside of `#myID` — every `<div>`s inside of an element with ID `myID`.

Answer (score 2):

The two syntaxes are both valid, but do different things.

`div#myID` will select a `<div>` which has the ID of `myID`.

`#myID div` will select a `<div>` which is contained inside another element (of any type) which has the ID of `myID`.

To give an example, using the following HTML code:

```
<div id='myID'>
  <div id='somethingElse'>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the first selector, you will select the outer div above. With the second selector, you will select the inner of the two divs.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
#myID div { }
```

Styles divs that come after `#myId`

```
div#myID {  }
```

Styles a div with the id of `#myId`

It depends on what your trying to achieve in order to suggest which one you should use.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't the same!

```
div#myID
```

applies to this:

```
<div id="myID">
</div>
```

`#myID div` does *not* apply to the example above, but to the text inside the following `div` container:

```
<p id="myID">
  <div>
  </div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`div#myID {  }`  will only target a div with the id of `myId`

`#myID div {   }`  will target child divs with an id of `myId`

Answer (score 0):

The first selector will apply to a `div` with the ID of `myID`.

The second will apply to all `div` tags within an element with an id of `myID`. This is clearly different.